# how to set focus on textbox in oracle form?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I want to set focus with cursor by default on textbox when open or start the oracle form

how to achieve this target in oracle forms 11g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that item is the first navigable item in a form, you don't have to do anything.

If it is not, create the `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger and put

```
go_item('block_name.text_item_name');
```

in there.

Comment: Thanks Bro @littlefoot

Comment: i add go_item focus on textitem when button press but when button press then written in textitem with blue highlight how to remove highlight

Comment: It happens when there's something written in the item, right? If so, the "blue" selection disappears if you move the cursor "left" or "right" by pressing these arrows on the keyboard. I don't think that there are appropriate KEY-LEFT or KEY-RIGHT triggers, but there **are** KEY-UP or KEY-DOWN, so you could try with `do_key('key-down'); do_key('key-up');`. That might work if there are no other records involved. Give it a try. Otherwise, I don't think that you can do it easily; maybe with some help of JavaBeans, but I don't know anything about that.

Comment: @RamizTariq Rather than doing the KEY triggers Littlefoot suggests, you could set the Keep Cursor Position property of the target item to Yes, and then it would not highlight the value in blue when the cursor moved there.

Comment: @littlefoot How to set the focus a a Swing element in a Java bean?

Comment: Sorry, @dmak; as I said, I don't know JavaBeans. I know they exist, but - no idea how they work.